# How to use the canonical and hreflang in ccTLD?

Tags: seo, canonical-url, hreflang

If I have two websites with same content 
example.com/de/ - in German, example.com - is in English, and example.at - in German.

so what would be the better option to implement canonical and Hreflang:

Am I right If I do like:

use canonical tag in both sites as self canonical and then also use Hreflang on the same time like:

```
link rel="canonical" href="http://example.com/"
link rel="canonical" href="http://example.com/de/"
link rel="canonical" href="http://example.at"

link rel="alternate" href="http//www.example.com/de/ " hreflang="de"
link rel="alternate" href="http//www.example.at/ " hreflang="de-at"
link rel="alternate" href="http//www.example.com/ " hreflang="en"
```

Or there is any other better way to do it? Is there no problem if we use canonical and hreflang at the same time?

Please let me know your thoughts about it.

Thanks,
Sahil

Answer (score 1):

On example.com use:

```
<html lang="en">
```

and

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://example.com/" />
<link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com/" hreflang="en" />
<link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com/de/" hreflang="de-de" />
<link rel="alternate" href="http://example.at/" hreflang="de-at" />
```

On example.com/de/ use:

```
<html lang="de-DE">
```

and

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://example.com/de/" />
<link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com/de/" hreflang="de-de" />
<link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com/" hreflang="en" />
<link rel="alternate" href="http://example.at/" hreflang="de-at" />
```

On example.at use:

```
<html lang="de-AT">
```

and

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://example.at/" />
<link rel="alternate" href="http://example.at/" hreflang="de-at" />
<link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com/" hreflang="en" />
<link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com/de/" hreflang="de-de" />
```

It will help Google to correctly recognize your language versions.

Additional notes: 
You can also use this [hreflang generator](https://www.aleydasolis.com/english/international-seo-tools/hreflang-tags-generator/) and validate it using [this tool](http://flang.dejanseo.com.au/). Lang attribute for html tag is needed for [Bing](https://blogs.bing.com/webmaster/2011/03/01/how-to-tell-bing-your-websites-country-and-language/).

Comment: I'm voting this down as 1. 'at' is not a valid language code and 2. it wasn't stated they wanted to target the USA with  the main domain or Germany with the de subfolder.

Comment: @Max Please have a look now it is de-at, so it's correct now. For English content it's now only "en" instead of "en-us". It was stated that they want example.com/de/ - in German (please have a look at the very beginning of the post). Could you please +1 back in this case? I also added additional notes.

Comment: It's stated in 'German', which means the language, it's not stated they want to target only Germany locale. 

I'd remove the location tags, leaving only the language.